# Align div top right-top corner

Tags: css, cross-browser, android-browser

Got problem with Android native browsers which doesn't recognize top right corner (it's rather like 20px from right corner.) The issue can be fixed by setting static width or by disabling page scaling, but unfortunately those aren't options for me.

CSS so far:

```
#rightCorner {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Also div disappears when zooming in.
Have tried Android versions: 2.2 and 2.3.4

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yV84W/2/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't the Android browser span this paragraph over the full browser width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418333/why-wont-the-android-browser-span-this-paragraph-over-the-full-browser-width)